# Is there an error in my code that explains why TouchableOpacity doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, touchableopacity

Hi  I'm following a ShoppingList app project/React Native crash course at the moment and I'm to the point where his Touchable Opacity is working and mine is not :(

I was curious if I have made a mistake or something I've checked my code versus the video side by side but maybe missed something.. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
  View,
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  TextInput, 
  TouchableOpacity, 
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome';

const AddItem = ({title,addItem}) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const onChange = textValue => setText(textValue);

  return (
    <View>
        <TextInput 
            placeholder="Add item..." 
            style={styles.input} 
            onChangeText={onChange}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.btn} 
            onPress={() =>
              addItem(text)}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>
              <Icon name="plus" size=
                  {20} /> Add Item
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
      height: 60,
      padding: 8,
      fontSize: 16,
  },
  btn: {
      backgroundColor: '#c2bad8',
      padding: 9,
      margin: 5,
  },
  btnText: {
      color: 'darkslateblue',
      fontSize: 20,
      textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default AddItem;
```

Comment: can you show the `addItem` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

In your Textinput, you are not passing the text with the function call

**Do this**

```
<TextInput 
    placeholder="Add item..." 
    style={styles.input} 
    onChangeText={() => onChange(text)}
/>
```

Comment: Did you get your answer?